# Sonar - Find a word in source code

Tags: sonarqube

It is possible to add a restriction (rule) in Sonar that finds a sentence in source code?
For example, to avoid things like *assertTrue(true)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an XPath rule that will search for those cases. There's a [documentation page that explains how to do that](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules).

Basically:

- Use the [SSLR Toolkit provided for the Java language](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem#JavaEcosystem-ToGoFurther) (search for the link called "SSLR Java Toolkit.") to determine the XPath query that will allow you to detect what you want
- In your Java profile, make a copy of the "XPath rule" ([see this rule on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/134?sort_by=SORT_BY_RULE_NAME&searchtext=XPath&rule_activation=any&status%5B%5D=READY&commit=Search)) and set the XPath query
- Once you have created this new rule, make sure you activate it on your profile and launch a new analysis

Comment: link does not open. ` documentation page that explains how to do that.`